# Ansible variable parsing order

Tags: ansible

Suppose I have a folder (group var folder) in which there are multiple sub folders. The folder names are based on version number such as 1.0.1 and 1.1.1 etc. If I define the same variable in multiple sub folders, which one will Ansible pick?

Comment: Sorry typo. What I mean is I have a group var folder  (sub folder) which contains the same variable

Answer (score 2):

All files in your group var folder and subfolders will be applied recursively.
Files and folders are sorted alphabetically on every level before processing.
The last processed variable assignment wins.

Here is the example of processing order:

```
./group_vars/testit/1.yml
./group_vars/testit/v0
./group_vars/testit/v0/1.yml
./group_vars/testit/v1
./group_vars/testit/v1/1.yml
./group_vars/testit/z.yml
```

In this case if `testvar` is `a` in `v0/1.yml` and `b` in `v1/1.yml`, `testvar` will have `b` value in the end.